# ruby on rails: submit a form clicking a check_box using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, checkbox

I have a form. I added a JQuery onchange submit to the number_field tag. The same i want to do for the check_box_tag. I want that the form get submitted if you click on one checkbox. i tried many options but i don't get it. Hope you can help me.

```
<%= form_tag("/rooms/list", method: "get", :name => "list", :remote => true) do %>
    <%= label_tag(:size, "gewünschte Raumgröße:") %>
    <%= number_field(:room, :size, in: 0.0..999999999, step: 1.0, :value => @size, :onchange => ("javascript: document.list.submit();")) %>
    <br>
    Equipment
    <br>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
        <%= check_box_tag(category, {:remote => true, :onclick => ("javascript: document.list.submit();")}) %>
        <%= label_tag(category, category) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, give an ID to your form and then write like "$(#ID).submit();", May these will solve your problem, If not then will suggest you another way. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

```
<%= check_box_tag(category,true, false, :onclick => "javascript: document.list.submit();") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

@killerameise below solution works in >rails 4.2

```
<%= check_box_tag(category, category, false, onclick: "javascript: $(this).submit();") %>
```