# f.checkbox - how to add onclick that submits instantly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have a check_box in rails 5, and I want it to submit instantly whenever it is clicked/unclicked. It should be possible with :onclick, but I'm new to js/jquery/ajax, and haven't had any luck searching.

I have this:

```
<%= form_for @client, :url => url_for(:controller => 'client_admin', :action => 'clientadminpageupdate') do |f| %>

<%= f.check_box :visible, :id => "checkbox" %>

<%= f.submit 'Save' %>
```

What I want to this is submit the form **instantly** by adding an

> :onclick => something-that-submits-the-form-instantly

How do I go about it?

Comment: Here you'll find your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243479/ruby-on-rails-submit-a-form-clicking-a-check-box-using-jquery

Comment: While that is somehow similar to my question, I tried that, and couldn't make it work out. Hence I opened this more specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to use it as a form submission you can use the following:

`:onclick => "this.form.submit()"`

Comment: That was it. Thanks!